# why won't google dataflow templates run for me

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, java-8, google-cloud-dataflow

I am hoping to use the TEXTIOtoBigQuery template provided by Google Cloud as a Google provided template to take a csv file and store in BigQuery. I set it all up correctly and tried running it but it failed due to being an external IP... my organisation won't allow us to use it so suggested we download and compile the source internally and use it this way..

The source code is avaialble at: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates

I have took an exact copy of this repo and saved it to my local pc. I have then ensured I have Java 8 sdk installed and running on my pc. In my head it should be easy right? an exact copy of their code? should just compile instantly?

I keep getting the below error though.. and can't figure out what I am doing wrong... is anyone else able to take this repo and install it locally?

To confirm I run the mvn install command and get the below output.. I am very new to maven and java, so any help appreciated.

```
Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: windows
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.version: 10.0
[INFO] os.detected.version.major: 10
[INFO] os.detected.version.minor: 0
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: windows-x86_64
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------< com.google.cloud.teleport:google-cloud-teleport-java >--------
[INFO] Building Google Cloud Teleport 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce) @ google-cloud-teleport-java ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) @ google-cloud-teleport-java ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- protobuf-maven-plugin:0.5.1:compile (default) @ google-cloud-teleport-java ---
[INFO] No proto files to compile.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- protobuf-maven-plugin:0.5.1:compile-custom (default) @ google-cloud-teleport-java ---
[INFO] No proto files to compile.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- avro-maven-plugin:1.8.2:schema (default) @ google-cloud-teleport-java ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ google-cloud-teleport-java ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.2:compile (default-compile) @ google-cloud-teleport-java ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 143 source files to C:\Users\607792223\OneDrive - BT Plc\Documents\Dataflow repo\DataflowTemplates-main\DataflowTemplates-main\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[18,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[52,37] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[60,27] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[135,30] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[264,13] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[320,33] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[378,49] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[20,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeCode
  location: package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[379,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Type
  location: package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[395,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Type
  location: package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[200,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeCode
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[210,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeCode
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[212,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeCode
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[216,5] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeCode
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[220,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeCode
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/InformationSchemaScanner.java:[21,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextRowToMutation.java:[21,73] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportProtos.ImportManifest does not exist  
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextRowToMutation.java:[56,63] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextRowToMutation.java:[69,53] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextRowToMutation.java:[138,25] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[21,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[22,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[267,86] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Export
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[276,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Export
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform.ReadExportManifestFile
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[291,20] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Export
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform.ReadExportManifestFile
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[304,82] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TableManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[313,35] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TableManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform.ReadTableManifestFile
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[347,35] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Export
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform.CreateTables
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[379,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Export
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform.CreateTables
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[562,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Export
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[570,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Export
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform.ReadManifestFiles
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[624,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TableManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[645,67] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TableManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform.ValidateInputFiles
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[669,69] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TableManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform.ValidateInputFiles
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[19,58] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[20,73] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportProtos.ImportManifest does not exist[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[204,65] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[208,55] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[302,74] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ImportManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportTransform
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[311,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ImportManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportTransform.ReadImportManifest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[324,20] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ImportManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportTransform.ReadImportManifest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[343,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ImportManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportTransform
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[356,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ImportManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportTransform.ResolveDataFiles
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[433,42] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TableManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportTransform.ResolveDataFiles
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[481,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ImportManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportTransform
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[481,82] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[485,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ImportManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportTransform.ReadTableColumns
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextImportTransform.java:[484,54] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[23,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[24,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[662,56] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[662,76] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[665,23] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[670,51] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[670,23] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[682,69] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[682,23] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[691,56] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[691,23] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[697,63] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[707,29] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[786,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TableManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportTransform.BuildTableManifests
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportTransform.java:[795,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TableManifest
  location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportTransform.BuildTableManifests
[INFO] 63 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  41.272 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-26T22:12:18+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.2:compile (default-compile) on project google-cloud-teleport-java: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[18,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[52,37] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[60,27] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[135,30] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[264,13] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[320,33] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/Ddl.java:[378,49] package Export does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[20,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TypeCode
[ERROR]   location: package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[379,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Type
[ERROR]   location: package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[395,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Type
[ERROR]   location: package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[200,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TypeCode
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[210,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TypeCode
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[212,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TypeCode
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[216,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TypeCode
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/common/Type.java:[220,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TypeCode
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.common.Type.Code
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ddl/InformationSchemaScanner.java:[21,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextRowToMutation.java:[21,73] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.TextImportProtos.ImportManifest does not exist  
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextRowToMutation.java:[56,63] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextRowToMutation.java:[69,53] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/TextRowToMutation.java:[138,25] package TableManifest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[21,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[22,54] package com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ExportProtos does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[267,86] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Export
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYPC/Documents/Dataflow repo/DataflowTemplates-main/DataflowTemplates-main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ImportTransform.java:[276,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Export
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.spanner.ImportTransform.ReadExportManifestFile
```

...

Comment: You are probably missing the java files which must be generated from .proto files of src/main/proto, namely export.proto.

Those files should be generated by the plugin protobuf-maven-plugin.
But here in the output you can see:


> [INFO] --- protobuf-maven-plugin:0.5.1:compile-custom (default) @ google-cloud-> teleport-java ---
> [INFO] No proto files to compile.


So it means it cannot find them. Can you double check that these files are present in your cloned repo ?

Comment: Okay thanks - I can see them in the repo I copied...  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/main/src/main/proto   will double check mine explicitly tomorrow... I did read something about compiling the proto plugins before compiling the rest of the code but unsure how to do that...

Comment: if the pom file is properly working you shouldn't have anything more than running the compile target to do it... But with old dataflow templates like this one we sometimes face misconfiguration issues so let's see...

Comment: Can you try following the instructions `mvn clean compile` in the repo to build the project? If you are using Intellij, there could be skipped maven goals: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates#buildingtesting-from-intellij